# Bash - replace in file strings from first array with strings from second array

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh

I have two arrays. The first one is filled with values `grep`ed from the file that I want to replace with the new ones downloaded.

Please note that I don't know exactly how the first array will look like, meaning some values will have **_**, other **-** and some won't have any of that and immediately after the name will be placed **:** (colon).

Example arrays:

> array1:
>
> [account:123 shoppingcart-1:123 notification-core_1:123 notification-dispatcher_core_1:123 notification-dispatcher-smschannel_core_1:123]
>
> array2:
>
> [account_custom_2:124 shoppingcart_custom_2:124 notification_custom_2:124 notification-dispatcher_custom_2:124 notification-dispatcher-smschannel_custom_2:124]

Those arrays are the only example, there are more than 50 values to replace.

I am doing a comparison of every item in the second array with every item in the first array as shown below:

```
file_name="<path_to_file>/file.txt"
for i in "${!array1[@]}"
do
        for j in "${!array2[@]}"
        do
                array_2_base="`echo ${array2[$j]} | awk -F_ '{print $1}'`"
                if [[ "${array1[$i]}" == *"$array_2_base"* ]]
                then
                        sed -i "s=${array1[$i]}=${array2[$j]}=g" $file_name
                 fi
        done
done
```

Here I substring only the first part for every item in the second array so I can compare it with the item in the first array.

e.g. **account_custom_2:124** -> **account** or **notification-dispatcher_custom_2:124** -> **notification-dispatcher**.

This works nice but I encounter problem when *notification* is in ***notification-core_1:123*** and ***notification-dispatcher_core_1:123*** and ***notification-dispatcher-smschannel_core_1:123***.

Can you please give advice on how to fix this or if you can suggest another approach to this?

Comment: the complexity of your script *might* be reaching a tipping point. Once you start juggling arrays in Bash, it's worth considering if your program is outgrowing a simple shell script (a 'glue' language running a sequence of commands with minimal data manipulation or complex branching logic). You might want to consider refactoring into something like Python/Perl/Ruby/anything-not-shell-script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is the `base` of array2 element may include other element
as a substring and will cause an improper replacement depending on the order
of matching.
To avoid this, you can `sort` the array in descending order so the
longer pattern comes first.

Assuming the strings in the arrays do not contain tab characters, would
you please try:

```
file_name="<path_to_file>/file.txt"
array1=(account:123 shoppingcart-1:123 notification-core_1:123 notification-dispatcher_core_1:123 notification-dispatcher-smschannel_core_1:123)
array2=(account_custom_2:124 shoppingcart_custom_2:124 notification_custom_2:124 notification-dispatcher_custom_2:124 notification-dispatcher-smschannel_custom_2:124)

# insert the following block to sort array2 in descending order
array2=( $(for j in "${array2[@]}"; do
    array_2_base=${j%%_*}
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$array_2_base" "$j"
done | sort -r | cut -f2-) )

# the following code will work "as is"
for i in "${!array1[@]}"
do
    for j in "${!array2[@]}"
    do
        array_2_base="`echo ${array2[$j]} | awk -F_ '{print $1}'`"
        if [[ "${array1[$i]}" == *"$array_2_base"* ]]
        then
            sed -i "s=${array1[$i]}=${array2[$j]}=g" "$file_name"
            delete="${array1[$i]}"
            array1=( "${array1[@]/$delete}" )
        fi
    done
done
```

The script above will be inefficent in execution time due to the repetitive
invocation of `sed -i` command.
The script below will run faster
by pre-generating the `sed` script and executing it just once.

```
file_name="<path_to_file>/file.txt"
array1=(
    account:123
    shoppingcart-1:123
    notification-core_1:123
    notification-dispatcher_core_1:123
    notification-dispatcher-smschannel_core_1:123
)
array2=(
    account_custom_2:124
    shoppingcart_custom_2:124
    notification_custom_2:124
    notification-dispatcher_custom_2:124
    notification-dispatcher-smschannel_custom_2:124
)

while IFS=$'\t' read -r base a2; do     # read the sorted list line by line
    for a1 in "${array1[@]}"; do
        if [[ $a1 == *$base* ]]; then
            scr+="s=$a1=$a2=g;"         # generate sed script by appending the "s" command
            continue 2
        fi
    done
done < <(for j in "${array2[@]}"; do
    array_2_base=${j%%_*}               # substring before the 1st "_"
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$array_2_base" "$j"
                                        # print base and original element side by side
done | sort -r)

sed -i "$scr" "$file_name"              # execute the replacement at once
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tested it and it is working (second suggestion).

Answer (score 1):

If number of items in your arrays are equal then you can process them in one loop

```
for i in "${!array1[@]}"; {
    value=${array1[$i]}
    new_value=${array2[$i]}
    sed -i "s/$value/$new_value/" file
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I don't know how many items are going to be downloaded so I don't know if arrays are going to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix this.

I am deleting string from the first array once replaced.

```
file_name="<path_to_file>/file.txt"
for i in "${!array1[@]}"
do
        for j in "${!array2[@]}"
        do
                array_2_base="`echo ${array2[$j]} | awk -F_ '{print $1}'`"
                if [[ "${array1[$i]}" == *"$array_2_base"* ]]
                then
                        sed -i "s=${array1[$i]}=${array2[$j]}=g" $file_name
                        delete="${array1[$i]}"
                        array1=( "${array1[@]/$delete}" )
                 fi
        done
done
```

Comment: It seems to replace `notification-core_1:123` with `notification_custom_2:124` and `notification-dispatcher_core_1:123` also with `notification_custom_2:124`. Are they your desired substitutions?